# SQL Arrays as parameters to prepared statements - portability

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, h2

I am working with PostgreSQL for my production machines, H2 to make unit tests on the DAO level sane, and Java/JDBC for the application level.

I would like to use SQL Arrays to implement bulk querying of my database.  However, the syntax expected by the two databases seems to be different!  In Postgres it is

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=ANY(?)
```

In H2, it is

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(id CHARACTER VARYING=?) NATURAL JOIN mytable
```

I thought that SQL was supposed to be standardized!  I decided to go read the actual standard, but apparently you have to pay money for that... Ridiculous!

Am I missing another way that is portable across databases?

Answer (score 1):

Standardized? Portability across databases? Ha! You made a funny. I've only come across arrays with PostgreSQL but Steven indicates that they're in SQL99; I don't know which syntax is standard (I'd guess PostgreSQL as they're usually pretty good with these things) but an IN query should work the same pretty much anywhere:

```
select * from mytable where id in (?)
```

You'd use a comma separated list of `id` values in the placeholder and you'll have to keep an eye on the size of the list of `id`s (and that size will, of course, be database specific).

Comment: A few websites claim that arrays were standardized in SQL99 and expanded in SQL2003, and therefore would not be a Postgres extension.  That said, your syntax does work.  Thanks :-)

Comment: @Steven: I've only come across arrays in PostgreSQL and wasn't aware that they were in recent standards. That said, I have found that databases lag behind standards even more than web browsers and C compilers :)

Comment: Can't believe I missed the IN syntax.  Wish I could've read the standard to find that out! :-p  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that this does not work!  It tries to treat the ARRAY value as a scalar and check equality i.e. id = "1,2,3" which is *not* what I wanted. :-/  It just happened to work for a single value...

Comment: @Steven: Not sure what you mean. Is something changing your `IN` to `=` behind your back?

Comment: No, apparently having an array argument in a ? is not valid.  You can say IN ('a', 'b', 'c') but IN(?) with the ? being an array means more like IN(['a','b',c']) which is not the same!

Comment: @Steven: So you need to include a bunch of `?` (one for each element in your array) and then bind the array elements individually? This is a couple months out of memory so I might be missing something.

Comment: correct, but then we are back to dynamically generating SQL which is a real pain and in fact then I start to run in to limitations on SQL line length...

Comment: I'm at a loss as I don't know what H2 will do with arrays. Are your arrays already inside the database in ome form? If they were then you could avoid the placeholder problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain standards that are consistent across database systems. In many cases, that's a baseline for implementation. Each individual system then builds on those standards in their own way.

It's an absolute nightmare to even think about trying to come up with something that is consistent across all systems. The best way to do this is to make sure you are limiting what you are doing to what is in those standards. Nothing more. If you go beyond that, for example, by using aggregate functions, you're on your own.

A few weeks ago, I thought I'd try implementing a system where I used PostgreSQL in dev/test and SQLite for my unit tests. I thought having an in-memory SQLite database would help me speed up my integration tests. While that part was true, the discrepancy in functionality between PostgreSQL and SQLite caused a number of headaches. After fighting through several different things (I was using NHibernate, too), I gave up and abandoned the thought.

The moral of the story? Portability/standardization don't mean much. Be consistent in what you're using across everything you're doing. You'll save yourself much grief.

Comment: Well, I figure as long as I stick to things that aren't too crazy I will be okay.  I got syntax that does work above.